# I want to print an html with header on each page except first in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, printing

I have an html which I want to print with fixed header on each page except the first page. I am using angular 4. How can I do it

Comment: Hey, this is a very broad question. Did you try anything so far? Did it work? What did not work?

Comment: Simply create one component for the same HTML and add it into root level in the `app.component.html` and make condition for first route